# Gulp & Git Plugin & JSON

Tags: json, git, gulp

I have a problem.. I have a huge JSON file that looks as follow:

```
{
    "name": "X",
    "type": "abc",
    "source": [
        {
            "version": "v1",
            "location": "x.git",
            "branch": "master",
        },
        {
            "version": "v2",
            "location": "x2.git",
            "branch": "develop",
        }
    ]
}
,{
    "name": "y",
    "type": "def",
    "source": [
        {
            "version": "v1",
            "location": "y.git",
            "branch": "master",
        },
        {
            "version": "v2",
            "location": "y2.git",
            "branch": "develop",
        }
    ]
}
]
```

What I need is to create - using GULP - a folder structure, where cloned git repositories will be found..

Desired folder structure:

- abc

  - X

    - v1 (inside that folder should be cloned git repo)
    - v2 (inside that folder should be cloned git repo)
- def

  - Y

    - v1 (inside that folder should be cloned git repo)
    - v2 (inside that folder should be cloned git repo)
  - Z

    - v1 (inside that folder should be cloned git repo)
    - v2 (inside that folder should be cloned git repo)

Is anyone able to help me? I tried with .pipe but without success.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Cheers,

Luke

Comment: I've already done that. No help is needed. I used gulp plugin: shell.

Comment: You can then post your own answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json = require('./*.json');
for (i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {

  name = json[i].name.toLowerCase().replace(/([^\w-])/g, '');
  type = json[i].type;

  for (j = 0; j < json[i].source.length; ++j) {

    version = json[i].source[j].version;
    json_loc = json[i].source[j].location;
    branch = json[i].source[j].branch;
    sources_loc = type + '/' + name + '/' + version;

    console.log('git clone -b ' + branch + ' ' + json_loc + ' ' + sources_loc);

    gulp.src('./')
      .pipe(shell([
        'git clone -b ' + branch + ' ' + json_loc + ' ' + sources_loc
      ]));
  }
}
```

That worked for me :)

Comment: Nice, don't forget to mark it as the answer when you can, this will help people with the same problem :)